# Is there a Standard Way to convert SQLCE Query Results to XML?

Tags: c#, xml, sql-server-ce, compact-framework, .net-1.1

I need to query a SQLCE table and convert the result set to XML. The columns of the database:

```
line_id     int
ref_no      nvarchar(20)
. . .
new_item    int
```

...have a 1:1 mapping to the required XML:

```
<INV>
<line_id>1</line_id>
<ref_no>valerie</ref_no>
. . .
<new_item>-1</new_item>
</INV>
```

I could generate this XML something like this (pseudocode):

```
int lineId;
String refNum;
. . .
String strXML;
StringBuilder sbXML;
. . . // loop through result set
lineId = resultSet[0];
refNum = resultSet[1];
. . .
strXML = String.Format("<INV><line_id>{0}</line_id><ref_no>{1}</ref_no>. . .<new_item>{2}</new_item></INV>", lineId, refNum, . . .newItem);
sbXML.Add(strXML);
```

...but this seems rather kludgy. Is there a more elegant solution?

### UPDATE

I used the first example from the link provided by ctacke, and now I have:

```
. . .
string xmlOutput = String.Empty;
. . .
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
doc.AppendChild(dec);
XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Command");
doc.AppendChild(root);

try
{
    while (dtr.Read())
    {
        // outer INV
        XmlElement invRec = doc.CreateElement("INV");

        // Line ID
        lineId = dtr["line_id"].ToString(); // Wiggly uses dtr.GetString(1); would then have to use GetX()...
        XmlElement _lineId = doc.CreateElement("line_id");
        _lineId.InnerText = lineId;
        invRec.AppendChild(_lineId);

        // Ref Num
        refNum = dtr["ref_no"].ToString();
        XmlElement _refNum = doc.CreateElement("ref_no");
        _refNum.InnerText = refNum;
        invRec.AppendChild(_refNum);
        . . .
        root.AppendChild(invRec);
    }
}
finally
{
    //doc.AppendChild(root); <= Should this be here instead of above?
    xmlOutput = doc.OuterXml;
}
. . .
```

### UPDATE 2

Or, for test code that can be lifted and dropped/plopped without any kind of setup:

```
private void button29_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string xmlOutput = String.Empty;
    String lineId;
    String refNum;
    String upcCode;
    String desc;
    String dept;
    String vendorId;
    String upcPackSize;
    String Id;
    String packSize;
    String unitCost;
    String unitList;
    String unitQty;
    String newItem;

    XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
    XmlDeclaration dec = doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", null, null);
    doc.AppendChild(dec);
    XmlElement root = doc.CreateElement("Command");
    doc.AppendChild(root);    

    try
    {
            // outer INV
            XmlElement invRec = doc.CreateElement("INV");

            // Line ID
            lineId = "some line id";
            XmlElement _lineId = doc.CreateElement("line_id");
            _lineId.InnerText = lineId;
            invRec.AppendChild(_lineId);

            // Ref Num
            refNum = "some ref num";
            XmlElement _refNum = doc.CreateElement("ref_no");
            _refNum.InnerText = refNum;
            invRec.AppendChild(_refNum);

            // UPC Code
            upcCode = "some upc code";
            XmlElement _upc_code = doc.CreateElement("upc_code");
            _upc_code.InnerText = upcCode;
            invRec.AppendChild(_upc_code);

            // Description
            desc = "some desc";
            XmlElement _description = doc.CreateElement("description");
            _description.InnerText = desc;
            invRec.AppendChild(_description);

            // Department
            dept = "some dept";
            XmlElement _department = doc.CreateElement("department");
            _department.InnerText = dept;
            invRec.AppendChild(_department);

            // Vendor Id
            vendorId = "some vendor id";
            XmlElement _vendor_id = doc.CreateElement("vendor_id");
            _vendor_id.InnerText = vendorId;
            invRec.AppendChild(_vendor_id);

            // UPC Pack Size
            upcPackSize = "some upc pack size";
            XmlElement _upc_pack_size = doc.CreateElement("upc_pack_size");
            _upc_pack_size.InnerText = upcPackSize;
            invRec.AppendChild(_upc_pack_size);

            // Id
            Id = "some id";
            XmlElement _id = doc.CreateElement("id");
            _id.InnerText = Id;
            invRec.AppendChild(_id);

            // Pack Size
            packSize = "some pack size";
            XmlElement _pack_size = doc.CreateElement("pack_size");
            _pack_size.InnerText = packSize;
            invRec.AppendChild(_pack_size);

            // Unit Cost
            unitCost = "some unit cost";
            XmlElement _unit_cost = doc.CreateElement("unit_cost");
            _unit_cost.InnerText = unitCost;
            invRec.AppendChild(_unit_cost);

            // Unit List
            unitList = "some unit list";
            XmlElement _unit_list = doc.CreateElement("unit_list");
            _unit_list.InnerText = unitList;
            invRec.AppendChild(_unit_list);

            // Unit Qty
            unitQty = "some unit qty";
            XmlElement _unit_qty = doc.CreateElement("unit_qty");
            _unit_qty.InnerText = unitQty;
            invRec.AppendChild(_unit_qty);

            // New Item
            newItem = "some New item";
            XmlElement _new_item = doc.CreateElement("new_item");
            _new_item.InnerText = newItem;
            invRec.AppendChild(_new_item);

            root.AppendChild(invRec);
    }
    finally
    {
        xmlOutput = doc.OuterXml;
        MessageBox.Show(xmlOutput); 
    }    
}
```

Comment: To make it more flexible, I'd not hard-code the element names.  Iterate through the fields in the ResultSet and use the names of the fields (which it can give you) to populate the name of the node.  This would make the code reusable, plus it would shorten the code a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You definitely do *not* want to use string formatting.  Since you're relegated to .NET 1.0 (there never was a .NETCF 1.1) then you'd use the [`XmlDocument`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmldocument(v=vs.110).aspx) class as the starting point and the use it to create nodes and attributes that you then add to the document.  It's pretty ugly compared to LINQ's `XDocument`, but it's the tool you have.

A quick search [turned up this example](http://paulsiu.wordpress.com/2007/04/04/creating-a-xml-document-from-scratch-without-using-a-file-in-c/), which is a good primer.

Comment: I tested the second example of that code in a modern app, and it worked great, but on pasting it into my handheld code, I find that the XmlWriterSettings class is unresolvable. Dang, I see here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlwritersettings(v=vs.80).aspx that XMLWriterSettings is new in .NET 2, and I'm on .NET 1.1 for this project, so I'm doomed.

Comment: ...not doomed after all, the first example seems to be acceptable.

Comment: I will award this after-the-fact bounty ASAP (23 hours).